# How to use type mappers with Slick Multi-DB Pattern?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using Slick 3.0 and following the [Slick Multi-DB Pattern](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/slick-multidb) so that the actual DB driver is abstracted. I use several type mappings which are defined in a single object TypeMappers. Now I want to abstract these type mappings from the particular DB driver too. This is why I moved TypeMappers into a dedicated trait. I believe this is the right approach, but I'm struggling how to import TypeMappers so that the implicits are visible for class User. Any help would be great.

```
trait TypeMappersTrait { this: Driver =>
  import driver.api._

  object TypeMappers {
    implicit val JavaUtilDateTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[java.util.Date, Long](_.getTime, new java.util.Date(_))
    implicit val URLMapper = MappedColumnType.base[URL, String](_.toString, new URL(_))
    implicit val WrappedByteArrayTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[WrappedArray[Byte], Array[Byte]](_.toArray, wrapByteArray(_))
  }
}


/** A User contains a name, picture and ID */
case class User(name: String, picture: Picture, id: Option[Int] = None)

/** UserComponent provides database definitions for User objects */
trait UserComponent { this: DriverComponent with PictureComponent =>
  import driver.simple._

  class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Option[Int])](tag, "USERS") {
    def id = column[Option[Int]]("USER_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("USER_NAME", O.NotNull)
    def pictureId = column[Int]("PIC_ID", O.NotNull)
    def * = (name, pictureId, id)
  }
  val users = TableQuery[Users]

  private val usersAutoInc =
    users.map(u => (u.name, u.pictureId)) returning users.map(_.id)

  def insert(user: User)(implicit session: Session): User = {
    val pic =
      if(user.picture.id.isEmpty) insert(user.picture)
      else user.picture
    val id = usersAutoInc.insert(user.name, pic.id.get)
    user.copy(picture = pic, id = id)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming you've got a typo in TypeMappersTrait and *Driver* should in fact be *DriverComponent* (so this self-type matches annotation up with UserComponent).

Then you can just un-nest your implicit type mappers from object TypeMappers so that they're sitting directly inside TypeMappersTrait, and pull them in via:

```
trait UserComponent extends TypeMappersTrait
```

Comment: This almost solved my problem but I had to import the type mappers as well:

    trait UserComponent extends TypeMappersTrait {
      import TypeMappers._